# Play 360 Video on IOS from Youtube iframe embed

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have some 360 videos hosted on youtube that I'm embedding as iframes on a website,

In IOS, the video does not work, it becomes split view and does not work with the build in gyroscope,

Can Youtube 360 videos embed work on IOS and if so how ?